Hi I am getting his error : Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
I a beginner in web developing, I am trying to build a todo list using MERN stack but when I try to render my todos on frontend (react app ), I encountered an error saying
Here's my code (App.jsx)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
import { useEffect,useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const[todos,setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect( () => {
    async function getTodos(){
    
      const response = await fetch("/api/todos");
      console.log(typeof response);
      const todos = await response.json();
      setTodos(todos);
    }
    getTodos();
   
  } ,[]);

  return (
    <main className="container">
      <h1>Awesome ToDo</h1>
      {(todos.length>0) && <div>{JSON.stringify(todos,null,2)}</div>}
    </main>
  );
}

Here's my API endpoints (routes.js)
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const connectToDb = require("./dbConnection");
const {ObjectId} = require("mongodb");

router.get("/todos", async (req,res)=>{
    let db = await connectToDb();
    let getTodo = await db.find().toArray();
    //console.log(getTodo);
    res.status(200).json(getTodo);
});



router.post("/todos", async (req,res)=> {
    let  db = await connectToDb();
    const {todo} = req.body;

    
    if(!todo){
       return  res.status(400).json({msg:"error: no todo found!"});
    }

    
    todo = JSON.stringify(todo);

    let insertedTodo = await db.insertOne({todo,status:false});
     res.status(201).json({todo,status:false,_id:insertedTodo.insertedId});
});

router.delete("/todos/:id", async (req,res)=>{
    let db = await connectToDb();
    const _id = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
    let deletedTodo = await db.deleteOne({_id});
    console.log(deletedTodo);
    res.status(200).json(deletedTodo);
});

router.put("/todos/:id",async (req,res) => {
    let db = await connectToDb();
    const {status} = req.body;    


    if(typeof status !== "boolean"){
        return res.status(400).json({msg:"invalid status type!"});
    }

    let updateTodo = await db.updateOne(
        {totdo:req.body.totdo},
        {$set:req.body},  
        {$set: !status}   
    );
    console.log(updateTodo);
    res.status(201).json(updateTodo);
});

module.exports = router;



I am trying to build a connection between frontend and backend.

It looks to me that when you fetch with /api/todos, you are getting HTML as response instead of JSON. Maybe the problem is because you are missing /api part in defined routes? Also check port from which you are fetching data.
